# Angular Return id of clicked div in ngFor loop

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2, and creating divs with an *ngFor loop. Here is the general structure, simplified:

```
<div *ngFor="let segment of segments ; let i = index;">
  <div></div>
    <div> 
     <button (click)="myFunction(index) )> click me </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Buried inside the each div is a button. I would like to call a function when the button is clicked and pass the index of the containing div. How would I do that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `<button (click)="myFunction(i)"> click me </button>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let segment of segments ; let i = index;">
  <div></div>
    <div> 
     <button (click)="myFunction(i)"> click me </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really thought I tried that, and that the inside div wasn't getting the id reference. Guess I was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As `@TsvetanGanev` suggested in the comments you can pass the index.

If you wanted to literally pass the segment which was clicked you can do:

```
<button (click)="myFunction(segment)"> click me </button>
```

if you wanted the javascript event:

```
<button (click)="myFunction($event)"> click me </button>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I set the shorter one to accepted, because it came in sooner and did the job.

Comment: @devinvail Don't forget you can also upvote people's answers - in this case. Glad I could help though.

Comment: Would love to, but I still need to increase my reputation for my vote to be recorded. One of these days I'll get there :-)